# GMSMapViewDelegate not being called

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I don't know but when I was still running my app in xcode 7 and run it on my iphone with ios 9.1, `didTapAtCoordinate` still works. But now after migrating to xcode 8 and upgraded the code to Swift 3 and running on my iphone with ios 10, the following seems not being called:

```
 func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        print("You tapped at \(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)")
    }
    func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, idleAtCameraPosition cameraPosition: GMSCameraPosition) {
        print("camera changed")
    }
```

I added this one `class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate`. And made sure that `mapView.delegate = self` is being called after the `mapView` has been initialized. The code below is in the `loadView`, I even added `mapView.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad`:

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 35.98917593, longitude: -95.94740106, zoom: 6.0)
            mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
            mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite
            mapView.delegate = self
            view = mapView
```

How do I troubleshoot this one?

Comment: I solved it already. Here's the revised event: ` func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)`. I added underscore before the mapView.

Answer (score 7):

You just have to initialize delegate at `viewDidLoad`

```
mapView.delegate = self
```